# How to keep a Garmin GTX330 turned off when powering on avionics?

Tags: avionics, transponder

There seems to be an option in the GTX 330 settings that keeps to unit from powering on when receiveing power from the power system.

I flew in two different airplanes and one immediately powered on the transponder, the other one keeps the transponder turned off, until I press ON.

Looking thru the Pilot's Guide and Installation Manual didn't give me any clue.

Can someone help? Seems like an undocumented feature.

Comment: In the manual I see the device does have the OFF button on the panel. Have you tried to switch it off with that button before removing the external power? After powering up, it would be logical for the device to return into the state where it was when the power was removed.

Comment: It turns on automatically when a certain altitude has been reached. I try to keep it also from that behaviour.

Comment: @David It doesn’t turn on automatically when takeoff is sensed, it changes from GND to ALT. The FAA recommends that you always be in ALT mode—even when on the ground—since many airports can now track you on the ground. There are settings that let you configure it to always be in ALT mode. You are required to be transmitting whenever you are in the air, so why would you want to turn it off?

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect it's a question of how the unit was installed. The manual says (emphasis mine) "The GTX 330 transponder is powered on by pressing the STBY, ALT or ON keys, **or by a remote avionics master switch (if applicable).**" It seems possible that one aircraft has it connected to the avionics master and one doesn't.

Comment: You might get a more useful answer if you can explain *why* you want to do this. And if the unit is on its own circuit breaker, you can always just pull that out.

Answer (score 3):

If pin number 1 on the back of the [GTX330](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/201/pn/010-00230-01) unit is connected to power (+), the unit will turn on. If it is not, you will have to manually press the on button. If you remove power from pin 1, it will not turn it off.

See the installation manual, which is findable by a simple [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03DgrREmujyB1MRtMF-wMcwKEYaLw%3A1611750037932&source=hp&ei=lVoRYOX4NYCl5NoPosaj4AE&q=garmin%20gtx%20330%20installation%20manual&oq=garmin%20&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgFMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyCAgAEJECEIsDMggIABCRAhCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzoECCMQJzoLCAAQsQMQgwEQiwM6BwgAEMkDEEM6BQgAEJIDOgoIABCxAxBDEIsDOg4ILhCxAxDHARCjAhCLAzoICAAQsQMQiwNQpwlYthBg1zBoAHAAeACAAYgBiAG-BZIBAzUuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXq4AQM&sclient=psy-ab)/[Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=garmin%20gtx%20330%20installation%20manual&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=garmin%20&sc=0-7&qs=n&sk=&cvid=6EE8AE8330884FA9BD3854509DBEB8ED) search, page D-1, figure D-1, Note 3.